# What do you call an object that resembles a concave triangle?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would you call a triangular object with two sloping, concave sides? See the following image. Consider object A, object B and the entire structure as a whole; object C. What do we call object C?

[image: Concave Triangle]

It is related to architecture. I'm trying to describe the structure of an opera house design proposal.

Comment: Technically, it takes 3 straight lines to make a triangle. The graphic you show looks like an "area under the curve" kind of problem. Can you give context? Is there a branch of mathematics where your graphic is a "triangle" as opposed to "triangular"?

Comment: @StuW: It is related to architecture. I'm trying to describe the structure of an opera house design proposal.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: How about an ***asymmetric double catenary peak***?

Comment: @Jim Not all curves are catenaries.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Never said they were. These looked like they might be though.  They are certainly not parabolic.

Comment: I will note that many probability curves and similar statistical functions resemble the above image, except that they usually do not have a sharp peak.

Comment: "I'm trying to describe the structure of an opera house design proposal." - So, it's a 3D object then? : [curved cone](https://www.google.com/search?q=curved+cone&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjggbu_isXPAhXGMz4KHZ2dBv8Q_AUICSgC&biw=1024&bih=639). *(offset) concave-curve finial (roof)*

Comment: So, what do you call a concavely curved triangle with a flat hypotenuse and an offset? I've have no idea... VTRO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I'd have agreed with Stu in the comments, but then I found that at least [one thing's 'official' name contains the word *triangle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle) and is not, in fact, composed of any straight lines.  There's also an article on Wikipedia for all sorts of *[circular triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_triangle)* and one for *[pseudotriangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudotriangle)*, if you want something more generic.

[Here](http://frederic.dupont8.free.fr/science/thesis/node9.html), in *figure 21.3*, something very similar to your drawing is referred to as a *curved triangle*, and [here](http://www.schillerinstitute.org/fid_02-06/2004/041-2_true_geometry.html), in *figure 3*, a triangle with all concave sides is called a *negatively curved triangle*.

**Therefore**, if you want to call that shape something with *triangle* in the title and stay in strictly euclidean geometry, maybe go with *curved triangle*.

Of course, [you can step outside of a flat-plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_geometry), (look at a triangle drawn on a sphere from the *inside*) but then your figure would simply be a *triangle* again, just on a different surface.

Answer (score 0):

In a general sense, I'd call your graphic a single segment of a **parabolic arch**. Such arches are used in long strands primarily for bridges. The Golden Gate Bridge is perhaps the most well known American example.

Comment: This is at best highly confusing; the default reading of 'parabolic' in this context is 'formed by [portions of] parabolas', not 'parabola-like'.

Comment: I'm thinking that a suspension bridge cable generally describes a catenary, not a parabola.